# mips-linux-uclibc-gcc: Command not found

Tags: c, openwrt, uclibc

How do I configure my micro libc buildroot and how do I use it? I am working on an 802.11p device and this still bugs me out. Do I use openwrt?

gab@ubuntu:~/Desktop/usr/src/locomate-release/mips/src$ make
mips-linux-uclibc-gcc -I /home/gab/Desktop/usr/src/locomate-release/mips/src/../incs -I /home/gab/Desktop/usr/src/locomate-release/mips/src/../socket-CAN/include -I /home/gab/Desktop/usr/src/locomate-release/mips/src/../src -c -DLOCOMATE -DSDK_NEW -o wsmpdemo.o wsmpdemo.c
make: mips-linux-uclibc-gcc: Command not found
make: *** [wsmpdemo.o] Error 127
gab@ubuntu:~/Desktop/usr/src/locomate-release/mips/src$ ^C
gab@ubuntu:~/Desktop/usr/src/locomate-release/mips/src$

Comment: This is saying that the 'make' command is not found.  Perhaps setting the path to the make executable or using ${MAKE}    On my linux system, the proper method of accessing make is /usr/bin/make.  Of course, what the error message is really saying is that the location of the make function is not listed in the ${PATH} environment variable

Comment: now it says mips-linux-gcc: Command not found only